# How to inject an object with Hilt onto a Library?

Tags: java, android, dagger-hilt

I'm developing two apps that use a common library between them. Each of them is using Hilt and Retrofit2 (with OkHTTP). I'll call the common library `Library`, and the apps `App1` and `App`.

`Library` has a Retrofit Api class for itself and each app has their own API that extends from the `LibraryAPI`.

`Library` and each app has a Hilt `NetworkModule` to provide the API to each respective Repositories: `app1` repository extends from `LibraryRepo`, same with `app2`.

The problem I have is that the settings for the Retrofit builder change depending whether I'm using `App1` or `App2`, but I do need to have `API` on the common library. Is there a way to tell the `LibraryRepo` to use the same API as `AppRepo` which extends from it?

A workaround I've thought of is to store in `SharedPrefs` if the build is of `App1` or `App2` and have an `if` inside the `provideApi()` method, but this seems a very inelegant way to do it, so I'm wondering what the best approach to this would be.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, which would be to use `getApplicationContext().getPackageName()` and use that to choose which one to use in each case.